# How to iterate through a PORTION of a TreeMap?

Tags: iteration, treemap, alphabetical

I'm doing an assignment where I have to search through keys in a TreeMap (that are mapped to files that they are found in. Basically, this TreeMap is an Inverted Index) that start with a query word that we specify to the program in a query file. However, for efficiency purposes, my professor does not want is to iterate through ALL the keys in the TreeMap when we look for keys that start with the query words, rather she wants us to iterate through only the keys that we need to iterate through. For example, if the query word starts with C, then we should only iterate through the keys that start with C. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: I suppose you mean the Java TreeMap? Can you describe more accurately the keys of the TreeMap? Also can you be more specific on "only the keys that we need"? In general, though, a TreeMap can only be iterated through completely.

Comment: Yes, the Java TreeMap. Sorry, these keys are String types in the TreeMap, so I only want to iterate through keys that start with the same letter as the query word. According to my professor there are ways to iterate through only parts of the TreeMap, but I'm trying to approach it this way (assuming that it's possible). Does this help clarify

Answer (score 1):

Use the TreeMap's `subMap()` method to obtain a SortedMap that contains only the range of keys that you want to examine.  Then iterate over that SortedMap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic implementation of what @ottomeister suggested:

```
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        TreeMap<CustomObject,String> tm = new TreeMap<CustomObject,String>();
        tm.put(new CustomObject(4,"abc"),"abc");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(7,"bcd"),"bcd");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(25,"cde"),"cde");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(18,"def"),"def");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(2,"efg"),"efg");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(8,"fgh"),"fgh");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(3,"aab"),"aab");
        tm.put(new CustomObject(13,"aab"),"abb");

        Map<CustomObject, String> sub = tm.subMap(new CustomObject(9,""),new CustomObject(20,""));

        for(Map.Entry<CustomObject,String> entry : sub.entrySet()) {
            CustomObject key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(key.getId() + " => " + value);
        }
    }
}

class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject>{
    private int id;
    private String Name;
    CustomObject(int id, String Name){
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull CustomObject o) {
        return this.id - o.id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

output:
13 => abb
18 => def